# Upload and Download Folder into database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Can I know is there any possible ways to upload folder (not files) that contain another folders into the database using php. Is there any method to store and retrieve them into the database?
Thank you in advance

Comment: This is a very vague question and not really the type of question appropriate for this Stack Overflow. Storing files inside a database is not the best idea, it is better to upload to a filesystem and then have links stored in a database.

Comment: Right now we have two roles, admin and users. Admin's job scope would be uploading the folders while users will export the folders. If I upload the folders into a filesystem...I am afraid other user will make change to the folder